# CreateSubKey is not creating entry in current user

Tags: c#, windows, registrykey

I am trying to create a sub key under Current user, Application runs successfully, but unable to create sub key under current user. Following is my application logic. Can any one tell me what mistake I am doing here?

```
RegistryKey myAppSettings = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\MyAppSettings");

Console.WriteLine(myAppSettings);
//storing the values  
myAppSettings.SetValue("appName", "C# Tutorials");
myAppSettings.SetValue("Demo", "Registry keys storage");


myAppSettings.Close();
```

Comment: this code is working fine on my machine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vivek, I retested, but still not working......

Comment: Run visual studio as admin and then try

Comment: Tried, but no use....

Comment: it might be related to permission then

Comment: Are you sure this piece of code is called? If yes, surely it's got to do with access permissions....

Answer (score -1):

CreateSubkey does not work with path values. You have to open the RegistryKey "software" and create the subkey for it.